# SVN checkout can not recognize resource path： svn:// ,but " file:/// " is ok

Tags: svn, svnserve

I create a repository,path is `d:svn/repos1`
When `svn` checkout,if the URL of repository is `file:///D:/svn/repos1`,it can checkout success,but if use the url of repository as `svn://localhost/svn/repos1`,then checkout failed.
and the error is "Unable to connect to a repository at URL `svn://localhost/svn/repos1`

add problem detail [my system is win7-64,i added the svnservice into operate-system-service and started it:(sc create svn binPath= "D:\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r d:\svn\repos1" DisplayName= "SVN"),and i didn't modify the default SVN-config file.]

Comment: OK - are you definitely running the svnserved? Is there definitely a service listening on port 3690 (try `netstat -an`) Is this Windows or Linux? (which affects which extra netstat options I might tell you to try)

Comment: My system is windows7-64bit, there is no service listening on port 3690 when I netstat -an,but i do operated like this:(sc create svn binPath= "D:\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r d:\svn\repos1" DisplayName= "SVN")and running the svn service.

Comment: Thank you Rup,i still don't know how to fix that problem,but i success to use VisualSVN server to continue my work.

Answer (score 4):

You have to setup and start [`svnserve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnserve.re.html) to be able to access your repositories using `svn://` access method. Otherwise you can setup Apache HTTP Server to expose your repositories via HTTP(S). I suggest reading the SVNBook chapter: ["Choosing a Server Configuration"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html#svn.serverconfig.choosing.svnserve).

If no server is configured to expose your repos, then you can access your repos via direct `file:///` URLs only.

Comment: In other words: when a client uses a file:/// URL, it acts like its own server. When you give it a svn:// URL, it tries to contact an independant server over a socket (network or otherwise). If there is no running server, then you cannot get a connection.